# Consumers not working when shutting down a broker in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I`ve have cluster of 3 brokers. The topic I'm using is configured with a replication factor of 3 and 4 partitions. I'm using the kafka python Api to set up the producers and the consumers.

My problem is that when I stop one of the brokers, in some cases, my consumers stop receiving messages.

```
(When broker 1 is unavailable):
Topic: frogakas Partition: 0    Leader: 5   Replicas: 5,3,1 Isr: 5,3
    Topic: frogakas Partition: 1    Leader: 3   Replicas: 3,1,5 Isr: 3,5
    Topic: frogakas Partition: 2    Leader: 5   Replicas: 1,5,3 Isr: 5,3
    Topic: frogakas Partition: 3    Leader: 5   Replicas: 5,1,3 Isr: 5,3
```

The thing is that when I shut-down any of the brokers, some of the consumer groups disappear. All of my consumers share the same group-id so, they stop working because their group is not in the group list.

When all of the brokers are available these are the groups:

```
root@m3-virtual-machine:/opt/kafka/bin# ./kafka-consumer-groups.sh  --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
test_group_kas
test_group_1
test_group_2
test_group
```

When the broker 1 is unavailable only test_group_2 is displayed:

```
root@m3-virtual-machine:/opt/kafka/bin# ./kafka-consumer-groups.sh  --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
test_group_2
```

At this moment, if i start a consumer with the groupId test_group_2 the messages will be received correctly.

I'd like to know if there is any way to avoid the service interruption when a broker falls.

Comment: Show `kafka-topics --describe --topic __consumer_offsets`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Kafka starts with `offsets.topic.replication.factor=1`

If you shut down the broker hosting your offsets topic, consumer group management won't work.

The listed group that remains is probably a mistake where you configured zookeeper instead of bootstrap servers.

Answer (score 0):

If a broker from a Kafka cluster fails, it can cause disruptions in service due to the drop in replication factor of partitions and unavailability of replicas. To avoid this, one option is to increase the replication factor to ensure that there are enough replicas available even in case of failure. Additionally, automatic load balancing between brokers can help avoid overload of a specific broker. It's also important to ensure that consumers and producers are configured properly to handle broker and partition failures. Kafka can provide status information so that consumers and producers can adjust their behavior in response to failure events.