# ClickHouse Kafka engine broker list: one is down

Tags: apache-kafka, clickhouse

We have 2 Kafka brokers in the ClickHouse Kafka engine broker list. Suppose one broker is down. In this case the ClickHouse stops receiving new events -- they are stored in the other Kafka broker for the duration of the retention time (1h). Then, when all brokers are up, the ClickHouse starts consuming events again.

Question: is there a way for ClickHouse to consume events from Kafka even if one of the 2 brokers is unavailable? Or is our cluster misconfigured, and ClickHouse must consume events in this case?

Comment: Hi grvsd - sorry to hear of the problem. Here at ClickHouse we're looking at your issue and trying to understand what might be causing this. A few questions/comments please: (1) are you using the ClickHouse Kafka Connect sink to connect these systems? https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/integrations/kafka/clickhouse-kafka-connect-sink and (2) similar to this other discussion, we're trying to understand if this is actually due to the sink or perhaps due to Kafka behavior: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76076385/consumers-not-working-when-shutting-down-a-broker-in-kafka - more to come

Comment: Hi Thom, 1) unfortunately we do not use Kafka Connect yet. We use https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/engines/table-engines/integrations/kafka. 2) thank you for the link, our replication factor is also = 1. It might be the cause.

Comment: Hi @grvsd, I am Kovi from ClickHouse. Have you figured this out? If not, I am up for helping you. In case you want me to help, can I ask for some logs? It would make my job tremendously easier.

Comment: Hi @JánosBenjaminAntal, no success yet. I have modified offsets.topic.replication.factor, transaction.state.log.replication.factor, transaction.state.log.min.isr in Kafka, was 1, set to 2. No result: when one Kafka is down, no events get to ClickHouse tables.
The ClickHouse logs were regular at that period, no errors, nothing suspicious. I'll reproduce later and will show it to you.